# Mongo complex sorting?

Tags: mongodb

I know how to sort queries in MongoDB by multiple fields, e.g., `db.coll.find().sort({a:1,b:-1})`.

Can I sort with a user-defined function; e.g., supposing a and b are integers, by the difference between a and b `(a-b)`?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Were you able to find a way to accomplish this on the server side? I'd really rather not have to do this on the client, or add the additional field.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This answer appears to be out of date; it seems that custom sorting can be more or less achieved by using the [`$project` function of the aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to transform the input documents prior to sorting. See also @Ari's answer.

---

I don't think this is possible directly; the [sort documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) certainly doesn't mention any way to provide a custom compare function.

You're probably best off doing the sort in the client, but if you're really determined to do it on the server you might be able to use `db.eval()` to arrange to run the sort on the server (if your client supports it).

Server-side sort:

```
db.eval(function() { 
  return db.scratch.find().toArray().sort(function(doc1, doc2) { 
    return doc1.a - doc2.a 
  }) 
});
```

Versus the equivalent client-side sort:

```
db.scratch.find().toArray().sort(function(doc1, doc2) { 
  return doc1.a - doc2.b 
});
```

Note that it's also possible to sort via an [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/sort/) and by the [`$orderby` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/orderby/) (i.e. in addition to `.sort()`) however neither of these ways lets you provide a custom sort function either.

Comment: Yup. After further digging I found that there's been an RFE filed to allow for convenience functions to do exactly this. I definitely don't like the looks of that `toArray()` for my ~10m documents, but that's apparently the state of affairs.

Comment: Hi @gilesc .Would you please tell me how did you exactly use 'RFE filed' in detail? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: @Wasabi I think he was referring to this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-153  It's not possible, but there's a ticket open where they are considering implementing it.  But it's been open for years, so not sure if it will ever happen.

Comment: Your sorting function may be wrong. It should be ``return (doc1.a - doc1.b) - (doc2.a - doc2.b)``

Comment: As demonstrated in @Ari's answer, you can use $project to implement your function and assign it to a field, and then sort on that.

Comment: there is a helpful article at http://koenaerts.ca/mongodb-aggregation-custom-sort/

Answer (score 19):

Ran into this and this is what I came up with:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
    $project: {
      difference: { $subtract: ["$a", "$b"] }
      // Add other keys in here as necessary
    }
  },  
  { 
    $sort: { difference: -1 } 
  }
])
```

Answer (score 11):

Why don't create the field with this operation and sort on it ?

Comment: I still need access to a and b individually.  So I'd have to create a third field.

That would work for my application, but as a general principle would be really bad policy.  Supposing I had several integer fields, there would be a combinatorial explosion of derived attributes (a-b), (a-c), (a-d)... Even with just one field like this, it's really wasteful of space especially for a large collection.

I'm upvoting and if no one else answers accepting, but there has to be a better way.  In SQL this is as easy as `SELECT * FROM coll ORDER BY (a-b)` .

Comment: Note that although you can do this in SQL, it is not very efficient. The database has to fetch all a and b values, calculate a-b, sort the results and return the associated records. With Mongo this would mean loading all documents into memory if you do not have an index on a and b. If you create a new field, you can create an index on this field, which will make this query really fast.

Comment: Great idea. As long as the value of a record's position is localized to data in the record itself, this perfectly amortizes the cost of computing the sort on insertion/update.