# MongoDB sorting

Tags: mongodb

I want implement a "bump" feature for topics.  Once a topic is bumped, it will have a new "bump_date" field.  I want to sort it so that when there is a "bump_date" field, it will be sorted as if it was the "created" field. Here's an example of my db.topics:

```
{
    "text" : "test 1",
    "created" : "Sun Nov 20 2011 02:03:28 GMT-0800 (PST)"
},
{
    "text" : "test 2",
    "created" : "Sun Nov 18 2011 02:03:28 GMT-0800 (PST)"
},
{
    "text" : "test 3",
    "created" : "Sun Nov 17 2011 02:03:28 GMT-0800 (PST)",
    "bump_date: : "Sun Nov 19 2011 02:03:28 GMT-0800 (PST)"
}
```

I want the sort to return in the order of "test 1", "test 3", "test 2"

Comment: It might help for MongoDB sorting http://www.code-sample.com/2016/07/mongodb-sort-by-date.html

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Sorting in MongoDB is done like so:

`db.collection.find({ ... spec ... }).sort({ key: 1 })`

where `1` is ascending and `-1` is descending.

In your specific example: `db.topics.find().sort({ bump_date: 1 })`, although it might be better to call it something like "updated_at".

You'll also definitely want to put an index on your "bump_date" field.

- sorting: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order
- indexes: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes

Comment: For this to work as expected, I think OP will need to set `bump_date` to `created` when saving the document for the first time. Then you always sort by `bump_date` and index on it, as you suggest.

Comment: That's true, and probably should be created so the collection can be eventually compacted. Or, [sparse indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-SparseIndexes).

Answer (score 5):

As Brian Hicks suggested, creating an additional updated_at field is the way to go. This way, when a document is created you can have created_at and updated_at initially be the same.

```
{
     "created_at": xxx,
     "updated_at": xxx
}
```

If you then "bump" the updated_at field by setting it to the current time when there is a a bump event you can sort on the updated_at field to achieve the ordering you desire.

Answer (score 5):

Also:

```
db.collection.find( { $query: {}, $orderby: { column : -1 } } )
```

where 1 is ascending and -1 is descending.

Comment: You answer me 3 years later, of course it changed... and now again...

Answer (score 3):

Currently it is not possible in mongodb to do a sort based on user defined criteria over multiple columns.eg. here the function would have been to return `bump_date` if it is set,else return `created`

Either you will have to use a server-side or client-side code as mentioned here :

[Mongo complex sorting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212919/mongo-complex-sorting)

or if you want to stay with basic quering and sorting, you shall :

- create a key `bump_date` equivalent to `created` whenever a new record is created. This will **not** be a data overhead, as you can expect every topic of yours to be bumped once in a while in future,hence `bump_date` field will eventually be added. So add it from the start itself.
- Whenever the article is bumped,update the field `bump_date` .

Your example documents will look like this with this change :

```
{
    "text" : "test 1",
    "created" : "Sun Nov 20 2011 02:03:28 GMT-0800 (PST)",
    "bump_date" : "Sun Nov 20 2011 02:03:28 GMT-0800 (PST)"
},
{
    "text" : "test 2",
    "created" : "Sun Nov 18 2011 02:03:28 GMT-0800 (PST)",
    "bump_date" : "Sun Nov 18 2011 02:03:28 GMT-0800 (PST)" 
},
{
    "text" : "test 3",
    "created" : "Sun Nov 17 2011 02:03:28 GMT-0800 (PST)",
    "bump_date: : "Sun Nov 19 2011 02:03:28 GMT-0800 (PST)"
}
```

You shall `ensureIndex` on bump_date field. Now you can query the required data easily.

```
db.topics.find().sort({ bump_date: 1 })
```

Comment: why ensureIndex should be applied to bump_date?