# How to make a leaderboard in mongoDB? nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, sorting

Hello actuallly i am tring to make a leaderboard command for my discord bot so wanted to make this

**User Shema Example**

```js
{ _id: something, points: 100 }
```

**I have every players in Array example**

```js
[
{ _id: something, points: 100 },
{ _id: something2, points: 300 },
{ _id: something3, points: 200 },
{ _id: something4, points: 50 }
]
```

I wanted to get points by ascending order by points then I want to get the name this is how it want to be like

```
something4 - 50
something - 100
something3 - 200
something - 300
```

Comment: show us what you have implemented(your mongo query)  till now.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Mongoose, how do I sort by date? (node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825520/in-mongoose-how-do-i-sort-by-date-node-js)

Comment: I couldn't find whats I need from there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206778/mongodb-sorting)

Comment: Please include in the body of the question the query you're currently using to generate the array of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_sort.asp),

```
MongoClient.connect("link_here", function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydatabase");
  var sortSelection = { points: 1 };

  dbo.collection("yourcollection").find().sort(sortSelection).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
});
```