# mongoose/mongodb custom sort

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a field in MongoDB that is a String type.  It will contain some combination of letters and numbers like "10", "101", "11", "112", "x115", "abc.5".  Right now if I tell MongoDB to sort these it will do an alphabetical sort, ordering as so:

- 10
- 101
- 11
- 112
- abc.5
- x115

It orders "101" before "11", how could I change the sorting so that numerals are ordered properly?

Comment: You'd need to zero pad the numbers to get them to sort consistently when stored as a string (and then remove the zeros later if needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use **[`db.eval`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/)** if you are determined to do this on the database-side.

[Answer extracted from another question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212919/mongo-complex-sorting)

> I don't think this is possible directly; the [sort
>   documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bsort%28%29%7D%7D)
>   certainly doesn't mention any way to provide a custom compare
>   function.
>
> You're probably best off doing the sort in the client, but if you're
>   really determined to do it on the server you might be able to use
>   `db.eval()` to arrange to run the sort on the server (if your client
>   supports it).
>
> Server-side sort:
>
> ```
> db.eval(function() { 
>   return db.scratch.find().toArray().sort(function(doc1, doc2) { 
>     return doc1.a - doc2.a 
>   }) 
> });
> ```
>
> Versus the equivalent client-side sort:
>
> ```
> db.scratch.find().toArray().sort(function(doc1, doc2) { 
>   return doc1.a - doc2.b 
> });
> ```

Comment: Given that eval blocks all reads and writes, `eval` isn't a good production-system option.

Comment: Here are the full set of warnings for it: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/. The summary is to not use it except in exceptional situations.

Comment: I linked to that in my post, most of them revolve around the exclusive lock not being disabled

Comment: It blocks all JavaScript & can't be used in a sharded system. That could be an issue.

Comment: You **can disable that lock behavior** using **`db.runCommand()`** rather than the helper, you can disable the lock by setting the `nolock` flag to `true` if the eval performs a strictly read-only operation.

and this **is** a strictly read-only operation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use collation with the `numericOrdering` parameter.
Example:

```
db.collectionName.find()
    .sort({fieldToSortOnName: -1})
    .collation({locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true})
```

Here locale: `en_US` is used for making a case insensitive search or sort.