# Mongoose: Sorting

Tags: javascript, mongoose

what's the best way to sort the following documents in a collection:

```
{"topic":"11.Topic","text":"a.Text"}
{"topic":"2.Topic","text":"a.Text"}
{"topic":"1.Topic","text":"a.Text"}
```

I am using the following

```
find.(topic:req.body.topic).(sort({topic:1}))
```

but is not working (because the fields are strings and not numbers so I get):

```
{"topic":"1.Topic","text":"a.Text"},
{"topic":"11.Topic","text":"a.Text"},
{"topic":"2.Topic","text":"a.Text"}
```

but i'd like to get:

```
{"topic":"1.Topic","text":"a.Text"},
{"topic":"2.Topic","text":"a.Text"},
{"topic":"11.Topic","text":"a.Text"}
```

I read another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720484/mongoose-mongodb-custom-sort) that this will require complex sorting which mongoose doesn't have. So perhaps there is no real solution with this architecture?

Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: It's working great. Your topics are strings and are being sorted as such.

Comment: this doesn't work because as I stated in my question the topics are sorted as strings so I get 1,11,2...

Comment: They are all documents in a collection. I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @qts Did the aggregate pipeline work for you?

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you make your `topic` filed as `type : Number`, and create another field `topic_text`.

Your Schema would look like:

```
var documentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    topic : Number,
    topic_text : String,
    text : String

});
```

Normal document would look something like this:

```
{document1:[{"topic":11,"topic_text" : "Topic" ,"text":"a.Text"},
        {"topic":2,"topic_text" : "Topic","text":"a.Text"},
        {"topic":1,"topic_text" : "Topic","text":"a.Text"}]}
```

Thus, you will be able to use `.sort({topic : 1})` ,and get the result you want.
while using `topic` value, append `topic_text` to it.

```
find(topic:req.body.topic).sort({topic:1}).exec(function(err,result)
{
    var topic = result[0].topic + result[0].topic_text;//use index i to extract the value from result array.
})
```

Comment: you mean create another field as follows: {"topic_number":1,"topic":"Topic","text":"a.Text"}?  I could do this but was wondering whether there was a less cumbersome way

Comment: I mean keep only topic field as Numbers 1,2,.. and when you use the topic value create another variable which appends topic number and ".Topic".

Comment: the problem is that the topic value can be any string not just 'topic'. {"topic":"1.apple"} or {"topic":"2.banana"} and I need to preserve the text

Comment: ohk, in that case that wont work. In that case try storing the number and the text in different `fields`

Comment: To implement your solution my schema would need to look like this: 'topic: {type: Number},{type:String}' which is not possible afaik. Or do you mean creating a list:  {topic:[1,'topic']}? If so I prefer to just use separate fields.

Comment: I suggested to create another field of `title_text : String` in the schema, along with `topic : Number` . I have edited again for you to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want (or maybe do not even can) change the shape of your documents to include a numeric field for the topic number then you can achieve your desired sorting with the aggregation framework.
The following pipeline essentially splits the topic strings like '11.Topic' by the dot '.' and then prefixes the first part of the resulting array with a fixed number of leading zeros so that sorting by those strings will result in 'emulated' numeric sorting.
Note however that this pipeline uses `$split` and `$strLenBytes` operators which are pretty new so you may have to update your mongoDB instance - I used version 3.3.10.

```
db.getCollection('yourCollection').aggregate([
    {
        $project: { 
            topic: 1,
            text: 1,
            tmp: { 
                $let: {
                    vars: {
                        numStr: { $arrayElemAt: [{ $split: ["$topic", "."] }, 0] }
                    },
                    in: {
                        topicNumStr: "$$numStr",
                        topicNumStrLen:  { $strLenBytes: "$$numStr" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            topic: 1,
            text: 1,
            topicNumber: { $substr: [{ $concat: ["_0000", "$tmp.topicNumStr"] }, "$tmp.topicNumStrLen", 5] },
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { topicNumber: 1 }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            topic: 1,
            text: 1
        }
    }    
 ])
```

---

[image: Working pipeline]