# Complex sort with MongoDB + Sails.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am developing a web application using Sails.js and MongoDB. I have to query the database and sort the results by a complex function. Actually is not complex, but is more difficult than sort by a key. In this case, I have this collection

**Users**

```
{ user : "Luis", key1 : 23, key2 : 29 };
{ user : "Juan", key1 : 53, key2 : 22 };
{ user : "Paco", key1 : 26, key2 : 42 };
```

And I'm trying get the results order by `key1 - key2`

I have tried different queries having [Mongo complex sorting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212919/mongo-complex-sorting) in account, but it didn't help me.

```
User.find({}).sort(function(doc1,doc2){return doc1.a . doc2.b })
 .exec(function(err,users){console.log(users)});
```

I have checked that this way runs ok in the Robomongo console (MongoDB GUI client).

```
db.eval(function() { 
    return db.scratch.find().toArray().sort(function(doc1, doc2) { 
        return doc1.a - doc2.a 
    }) 
});
```

But I am not able to implement this using Sails and waterline orm. I would use native connection if necessary but I don't know how to do it.

Please help me, thanks you a lot!

Comment: Do you mean sort by the different between `key1` and `key2`?

Comment: yes, I mean sort by the difference between `key1` and `key2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method which provides access to the aggregation pipeline. The first stage in the pipeline is the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage where you use the [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/#exp._S_subtract) operator to return the difference of "key1" and "key2".

The last step in the pipeline is the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) stage where you sort your documents in ascending order using `{ 'diffkey': 1 }` or descending order `{ 'diffkey': -1 }`.

```
db.user.aggregate([
    { '$project': { 
        'user': 1, 
        'key1': 1, 
        'key2': 1, 
        'diffkeys': { '$subtract': [ '$key1', '$key2' ] }
     }}, 
    { '$sort': { 'diffkeys': 1 } }
])
```

Which yields:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("567d112eaac525feef33a5b7"),
        "user" : "Juan",
        "key1" : 53,
        "key2" : 22,
        "diffkeys" : -31
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("567d112eaac525feef33a5b6"),
        "user" : "Luis",
        "key1" : 23,
        "key2" : 29,
        "diffkeys" : 6
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("567d112eaac525feef33a5b8"),
        "user" : "Paco",
        "key1" : 26,
        "key2" : 42,
        "diffkeys" : 16
}
```

You may be tempted to add another extra `$project` to the pipeline to filter out the `diffkey` field from your query result but doing so will cause a drop of performance. And generally speaking you shouldn't worry about one additional field in your query result.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean sort by the difference between `key1` and `key2` I don't think it can be done with a simple find, I think you'll need to use aggregation.

Note: I'm not familiar with Sail.js, so I'll write the query in mongoshell and let you translate to sail

```
db.user.aggregate([
{
    $project:{
        doc: "$$ROOT",
        sortOrder: { $subtract: ["$key1", "$key2"] }
    }
},
{
    $sort:{ sortOrder: 1}
}
]);
```

Not sure how exactly you want your final output to look, so you may want to add some another project at the end.

Comment: @luigonsec `$$ROOT` is a reference to the entire document being parsed. See docs on it [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/). Basically I didnt know what info you did or didnt want in your final output, so I just took all of it.

Comment: ["$key1", "key2"] - it should be ["$key1", "$key2"]