# Custom sorting function in mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have following code:

`.find(callback).limit(limit).sort({ id: -1 });`

Which works like a charm, actually. **However**, few of the collections may have `approved` field `undefined` (it may not exist). If so, they should be moved at the end of the list.

**Question**: Can I just pass to that `sort` function instead of that object `{ id: -1 }`?

My custom sorting function:

```js
const o = [{
  id: 4,
  approved: true,
}, {
  id: 1,
  approved: true,
}, {
  id: 2,
  approved: true,
}, {
  id: 3,
}];

const r = o.sort((a, b) => {
   return b.approved ? b.id - a.id : b;
});

console.log(r);
```

#### Edit: passing a custom function doesnt work, since `sort` expects a string/object or array.

Comment: You can do this using `aggregate` by projecting a custom value to sort on and then sorting on that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212919/mongo-complex-sorting

Comment: What happens if you [sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) on `{approved: -1, id: -1}`? That should work given that undefined fields compare smaller than booleans.

Comment: Confirmed `db.getCollection('<yourCol>').find().sort({ approved: -1, id: -1 })` returned what the OP wants.

Comment: @Akrion It did move the elements without `approved` at the end, however the elements with `approved` field are not sorted correctly. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: @Patrickkx based on my test all objects with no `approved` went on the bottom. Above them are all objects with `approved` false and then the remaining with `approved: true`. Is this not the desired output?

Comment: @Akrion First should go elements with `approved = true` and they should be sorted by `date` (I used `id` because its easier to show the problem, but in real im sorting them by `date`) AND THEN should go elements with `approved = false` and also should be sorted by `id` (`date`)

Comment: OK got it. You should have specified all that in the question. It is a little guess work  to get to here

Comment: @Akrion Hello, did you find any solution on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not a [consistent comparison function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24080786/1048572). You can't return the `b` object, and you should check for only `b.approved`.

Instead, use

```
arr.sort((a, b) => {
    return !!b.approved - !!a.approved || b.id - a.id;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as you can't use a JS function for sorting with mongodb regardless.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Oh, you're probably right. I don't know mongodb, but the OP talked about functions and used arrays in his question… But surely you can make mongodb sort by `approved` and then by `id`?

Comment: Sure, but the OP is looking to customize the standard sorting you'd get with that.

Comment: Dear Bergi, your solution moved the elements without `approved` down the list, however these elements WITH approve are not sorted properly :( just random...

Comment: Some of them got `approved = true` and some of them got `approved = false`. The solution u gave me works fine, I mean, it pushes the elements with `approved = false` down the list, but elements with `approved = true` are not sorted properly (they should be sorted by `id` (in real it's `date`, but it was easier for me to reproduce the problem with just `id`))

Comment: Im talking about solution `{approved: -1, id: -1}`

Comment: @Patrickkx That's weird, MongoDB docs claim that it would sort all values with the same `approved` value by `id` with that solution.

Comment: Does lack of `approved` field make a problem? Because it's not like approved can be true or false. It's `approved = true` or there's no approved at all (the field just do not exist)

Comment: @Patrickkx I don't think that matters. MongoDB can compare non-existing fields just fine, treating them as nil.