# Sorting returned MongoDB documents by custom criteria, not a field directly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

I store time in my record as string in format `HH:mm`, but in Node JS, I need to sort by this time field, but the problem is that it's just as string. First I need to map my time to `Date` object, is it even possible? my code so far:

```
    find({hairdresserId: ObjectId(id),
           visitDate: date}, {visitHourStart: 1, visitHourEnd: 1, _id: 0},
           (err, document) => {
               res.json({
                   typeOfDocument: typeof document,
                   vistsForThisDay: document.length,
                   visits: document
               });
           }).sort({visitHourStart: 1});
```

But `sort({})` should look more like `sort({Date(visitHourStart): 1})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongodb doesn't support custom sorting, therefore neither does mongoose.
To solve this, you can always do the sorting in the callback function (your `document` is an array therefore you can sort it however you want), or , if you really, really want to do the sorting mongodb side, take a look at this answer: [Mongo complex sorting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212919/mongo-complex-sorting)